# Recieve 3 files by terminal and concatenate the content of file2 and file3 to file1 using fstream

Tags: c++

I'm begginer in C++, so may be parts of my code doesn't have sense, sorry.

What I have to do is (C++, Linux, by fstream):

· Receive 3 or more files passed by terminal by:
  ./executable file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

· programm a function that read the files file2.txt and file3.txt and copy it to file1.txt  (concatenate, don't overwrite)

I don't know how to do it, I don't know anything about fstream, I'm just learning now by myself, so I really need help. Maybe there are similar questions solved in SO, but I don't know how to solve my problem by them.

I attach the code I have. I don't know how to code the function, so it's empty.

Thank you so much.

I try doing:

```
void concat(char *argv[], int numberoffilesreceived){

    char c;

    towritethefiles.open(argv[0], ios::app);

    for(int i=1; i<numberoffilesreceived; i++){
        toreadthefiles.open(argv[i], ios::in);
        while(!toreadthefiles.eof()){
            toreadthefiles >> c;
            towritethefiles<< c;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles but doesn't work, the program freezes when you run it.

and I also try using std::copy by I don't understand how it works.

```
ifstream toreadthefiles;
ofstream towritethefiles;

void concat(char *argv[], int numberoffilesreceived);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* 1/2 The code from below to 2/2 it's only to prevent path errors when receiving the files (it works fine) */
    const char directory[SIZE]="./";
    int count_files=0;
    char files[SIZE][SIZE];
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        strcpy(files[i], directory);
        strcat(files[i], argv[i]);
        count_files++;
    }
    /*2/2 to add ./ to the name files when passed by terminal: ./executable ./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./file3.txt */

    /*check if received almost 3 files like required */
    if(argc<3){
        cout<< "Error, to few files entered" << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    /*pass the files to the concat function*/
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){  
        concat(&argv[i], count_files);      
    }


    toreadthefiles.close();
    towritethefiles.close();

    return 0;
}

void concat(char *argv[], int count_files){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see an issue with your `concat()` function. You are calling `concat()` for each of the files passed in. Then in the function, you are using `count_files` to run that loop again for the number of files passed in.

I would consider rewriting `concat()` function so that it looks like this:

```cpp
void concat(std::ofstream& outputStream, char* fileToAppend)
{
    std::ifstream in(fileToAppend);

    if (!in) {
        cout << "Error, cannot open file: " << fileToAppend;
        return;
    }

    // Use std::getline to read each line in the input stream,
    // then write it to the output stream!
    string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        outputStream << line;
    }
}
```

The benefit being that you can reuse the function for appending a *single* input file to an existing output stream, and you wrap up the check to ensure the file exists (you may want something more sophisticated like returning true/false on the file being appended, or throwing an error, etc.).

In `main()`, you would replace the code after the check for at least three files with something like:

```cpp
    // Create an output stream with the first file
    // ios::out- output flag
    // ios::app- append flag
    std::ofstream out(argv[1], ios::out | ios::app);

    // Make sure the file exists!
    if (!out) {
        cout << "Error, cannot open file: " << argv[1];
        exit(1);
    }

    // For all other arguments, concat with the first.
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        concat(out, argv[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::copy` with stream iterators, and I've revised my previous suspicion that it would be slow, so here's one way using doing just that with comments in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ios>
#include <stdexcept>

void concat(const std::string& destination, const std::vector<std::string>& sources) {
    // open the destination file and keep it open until all is done
    std::ofstream dest_fs(destination, std::ios_base::binary);
    if(!dest_fs) 
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not write to \"" + destination + "\".");

    // loop over the source files
    for(const auto& source_file : sources) {
        // open the current source file
        std::ifstream source_fs(source_file, std::ios_base::binary);
        if(!source_fs)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not read from \"" + source_file + "\".");

        // copy from source to destination
        std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(source_fs),
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                  std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(dest_fs));
    }
}

int cppmain(std::string program, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    if(args.size() < 2) {
        std::cout << "USAGE: " << program << " destination_file input_file(s)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // extract the first argument which is the destination file
    std::string destination_file = std::move(args.front());
    args.erase(args.begin()); // erase first argument from the vector

    try {
        // do the concatenation
        concat(destination_file, args);
        return 0;
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << program << ": ERROR: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv + 1, argv + argc});
}
```